# 'AttributeError: module 'usbiss' has no attribute Aclass' when creating class instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module, python-packaging

Trying to write a python package and I cant create an instance of a class in one of my source files.

package layout is:

```
-packagedir
----README.md
----setup.py
----packagename
--------__init__.py
--------package.py
--------modules
------------file1.py
------------file2.py
```

in **init**.py within packagename i have:

```
from . modules import file1
from . modules import file2
```

The file file1.py contains a class:

```
class File1():
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 0
        # Other methods and such
```

The file file2.py contains a class:

```
class File2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = 0
        # Other methods and such
```

and in package.py I have a class as thus:

```
class Aclass(file1.File1, file2.File2):
    def __init__(self):
        # nothing important in here yet
```

I have build and installed my package like this:

```
python3 setup.py sdist
sudo pip3 install dist/package-0.1.tar.gz
```

Now I create a file called test.py and put in it the following:

```
import package
iss = package.Aclass()
```

when I run the test file i get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'usbiss' has no attribute 'Aclass'
```

I do not understand why it is that python is not letting me create an instance of class Aclass and thinks I am accessing an attribute. I am sure there is something fundamentally wrong with my import statements or something but i am at a loss as to what it is. How do I correct this so that I can create an instance of Aclass and use its methods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here was that  I was importing the package itself but not a module within that package. I changed my import in test.py to:

```
from package import package
```

and this fixed my issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In future, try not to name your packages with such generic names. It leads to a lot of confusion that frankly can be dealt with via proper thoughtful names

Comment: Yeah the class and module names were not final i was just playing as a proof of concept for making a python module as a learning exercise at the moment. Forethought could have avoided this altogether. There is a lesson in there, plan a bit more even if you are just experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are handling your `import` properly and not introducing any circular dependencies?
Also:

```
def __init__(file1.File1, file2.File2):
def __init__():
```

Your init methods are lacking `self`. They should be:

```
def __init__(self, file1.File1, file2.File2):
def __init__(self):
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, the __init__() methods so have self in them somehow i copy pastad them out of the question.

Comment: Have you solved for your problem already? If so, what is the solution?

Comment: Yes i have, just this moment realised what i was doing wrong. See my answer to my own question. thanks.